# logger.debug ["This is", "an", "Array"] Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Why is my output of

```
logger.debug ["This is", "an", "Array"]
```

This isanArray

and not something like
["This is", "an", "Array"]

Is there a way to do this? (I know I could do to_yaml, but that is too verbose for me)

What are some options for a nice clean output of an array, similar to print_r in php?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
logger.debug ["This is", "an", "Array"].inspect
```

This also works for all other kinds of objects: Hashes, Classes and so on.

Answer (score 1):

you could try the .inspect method....

```
logger.debug array.inspect
```

I agree with Andrew that there is nothing wrong with...

```
puts YAML::dump(object)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do that, [`to_s`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Array.html#M000291) is automatically called on the array, and that's how to outputs.

Calling `to_yaml` is by no means verbose. You could also look at using [`join`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Array.html#M000322) or [`inspect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Array.html#M000292).